# PN532 : Unable to open NFC device

Tags: pi-zero, nfc

I was working with the **PN532 V3** module and it was **working just fine** two days ago. Now I tried to connect it to the Raspberry Pi Zero again and when I run a simple `nfc-list` I get this :

```
root@raspberrypi:~/chip# nfc-list 
debug   libnfc.general  log_level is set to 3
debug   libnfc.general  allow_autoscan is set to true
debug   libnfc.general  allow_intrusive_scan is set to false
debug   libnfc.general  1 device(s) defined by user
debug   libnfc.general    #0 name: "PN532 over I2C", connstring: "pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1"
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using acr122_usb driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using pn53x_usb driver
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   Diagnose
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   Timeout value: 500
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   SAMConfiguration
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   Timeout value: 1000
debug   libnfc.bus.i2c  TX: 00 00 ff 03 fd d4 14 01 17 00 
debug   libnfc.bus.i2c  wrote 10 bytes successfully.
error   libnfc.chip.pn53x   Unexpected PN53x reply!
pn53x_check_communication: Input / Output Error
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   InRelease
debug   libnfc.bus.i2c  TX: 00 00 ff 03 fd d4 52 00 da 00 
debug   libnfc.bus.i2c  wrote 10 bytes successfully.
debug   libnfc.chip.pn53x   PN53x ACKed
debug   libnfc.driver.pn532_i2c timeout reached with no READY frame.
debug   libnfc.general  Unable to open "pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1".
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1
```

Which is weird because the Pi seems to detect the device :

```
root@raspberrypi:~/chip# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- 24 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

It already happened with another module. I thought it broke somehow so I bought a new one, and now again...

Can someone tell me what is going on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved !

I found out that I had to wire the PN532 **before** turning on the Raspberry Pi !